# Why Clang and GCC complain about this specific situation

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, cstdint

I have this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

typedef unsigned long long u64;

struct A{
    A(int a) : m_a(a){}
    A(u64 a) : m_a(a){}
    A(double a) : m_a(a){}
    u64 m_a;
};

struct B{
    B(int b) : m_b(b){}
    B(uint64_t b) : m_b(b){}
    B(double b) : m_b(b){}
    uint64_t m_b;
};

int main(){
    
    // This works
    unsigned long long a = std::stoull("10000");
    
    // And this
    auto a2 = A(a);

    // And this
    auto a3 = A(std::stoull("10000"));
    


    // This works
    uint64_t b = std::stoull("10000");
    
    // And this
    auto b2 = B(b);

    // But not this?
    auto b3 = B(std::stoull("10000"));

    return 0;
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/fMjxaYT8x)

Why does Clang and GCC complain about the very last example? Shouldn't it be the same as the third example? Can someone explain what is going on? What C++ features/rules are at play here?

Comment: Problem is that on 64 bit definition of `uint64_t ` (`long unsigned int`) is different then for 32 bits (`long long unsigned int`): https://godbolt.org/z/7P91jxhb9

Comment: `Why does Clang and GCC complain about the very last example?` It literally tells you why `error: call of overloaded 'B(long long unsigned int)' is ambiguous`. I do not understand.

Comment: `uint64_t` is `unsigned long` on 64 bit *Nix machines, not `unsigned long long`.  Moral of the story, don't mix types

Comment: How do they complain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the platform you are compiling, `uint64_t` is `unsigned long`, not `unsigned long long`.

You may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models .

> Why does Clang and GCC complain about the very last example?

They tell you why - the call is ambiguous, it is not clear which overload to choose.

> Shouldn't it be the same as the third example?

No. In the third case class `A` has a `unsigned long long` overload. In the last case class `B` does not have `unsigned long long` overload.

Comment: I did know Linux's long was 64 bits vs 32 on Windows but I didn't know uint64_t was defined as an unsigned long. That does explain everything. Thank you